# Adding image annotations to pdf with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I would like to use ghostscript to add an annotation to a pdf file, similar to the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427034/add-comments-to-pdf-files-automagically-with-regular-expressions).  However, instead of a text annotation, I want to add an image as an annotation.  Given what I have read in the pdfmark reference and the pdf reference, I think it should be possible by inserting a "custom" rubber stamp annotation.  If anyone could provide an example of how to do this, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to define an Appearance (/AP) stream for your annotation. If you want to use an image then the AP stream either needs to contain an inline image (assuming its reasonably small) or you need to create a Named Image so that your AP stream can refer to the image by name.

I don't have an example of a pdfmark to do this, but it should be reasonably easy to start by creating a stamp annotation with a simple appearance stream. Something like '0 1 0 0 k 10 10 20 20 re f' would draw a 10x10 magenta rectangle. After that you could move on to images.

Answer (score 1):

Example using Ghostscript: create a text file called my-pdfmarks.txt with contents:

```
% create a picture
[ /BBox [0 0 100 100] /_objdef {MyPicture} /BP pdfmark
1 0 0 setrgbcolor
0 0 moveto 100 80 lineto stroke
100 80 moveto 0 80 lineto stroke
0 80 moveto 0 0 lineto stroke
/Helvetica findfont 10 scalefont setfont 10 60 moveto (Hello World!) show
[ /EP pdfmark
% Now, the rubber stamp
[
/Rect [ 10 500 110 600 ]
/SrcPg 1
/AP << /N {MyPicture} >>
/Open true
/Subtype /Stamp
/ANN pdfmark
```

Then, run Ghostscript command like the following. I'm assuming Windows now -- for Linux/Unix/MacOSX use gs instead of gswin64c.exe for the executable, and use \ instead of ^ for the line continuation marks:

```
gs ^
  -o original-annotated.pdf ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
   original.pdf ^
   my-pdfmarks.txt
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).