# Annotation of PDF files with Ghostscript on Windows

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I try to annotate *PDF-files with Ghostscript on Windows*.

It works, but sometimes it returns error messages and the application of an annotation fails.

Can anyone tell what this error message actually means?

Here is a screenshot of the error message:

[image]

The command I used in this case:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin32.exe" -o ./work/result/2530
902.pdf  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress  ./work/result/2530902_b.pdf
./ann/2530902.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll update my answer accordingly, if you provide answers to the questions further below. Otherwise, I'll delete it again.

As the first guess, the `/syntaxerror in -file-` part of the screenshot suggests that your PDF file indeed contains a syntax error. I can only tell you...

- ...which syntax error exactly,
- ...whether this error could potentially be repaired/fixed,

...if you provide access to the PDF file for me (or anybody else).

The general method of using Ghostscript to add annotations to an existing PDF file is described here:

- **["Add comments to PDF files automagically with regular expressions"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4484293/359307)**

The command's structure has to be as the following (example tailored to the 32bit Windows environment):

```
gswin32c.exe                                      ^
  -o output.pdf                                   ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite                               ^
   [...other settings...]                         ^
  -c "...PostScript code to add annotation(s)..." ^
  -f input.pdf
```

Please take good note of the following:

1. there may be multiple occurrences of the `-c` parameter
2. the existence of the `-c` parameter followed by some code in quotes;
3. the order of the `-c` (for *command*) and `-f` (for *file*) parameters.

The `-c "..."` part ***can*** be replaced by a simple text file containing the content of the respective commands. But there is a strict syntax for annotation that needs to be respected.

***I'm not absolutely sure you can change the order of the two parameters in all Ghostscript versions.*** (The above link shows it could be done at a time, though.) Try to change the order of the parameters and see if it fixes the problem.

---

Here are my questions:

1. Can you provide (a link to) the PDF file resulting in the error message of the screenshot so I can check its syntax?
2. Can you please provide the contents of your file `./ann/2530902.txt` so I can check it for correctness?

Comment: Thank you. These documents are confidential so I can't give them to you :( and I can't generate test document.

Comment: @VesaAla-Hakula: But surely the content of `./ann/2530902.txt` is not confidential? If there *are* confidential snippets in there (like the text of the annotation), you could easily replace it with some random strings, no?!?